# Resize disk to Install windows 10 alongside Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, partitioning, windows, swap

**I have Ubuntu 16.04 running on below disk and I want to install Windows 10 alongside it**

[image]

My understanding is that the overall process should be:

1. Resize my disk to make space for Windows 10
2. Install windows 10
3. Install grub again so I can dual-boot Ubuntu/Windows

Regarding step 1, Gparted won't let me resize `ext4` because of the `swap` that's after, so I should do:

- Turn off swap
- Remove swap partition from `/etc/fstab`
- Resize `ext4` down to create free space for Windows 10 + new swap
- Recreate swap from some of the free space
- Leave some of the free space for Windows 10
- Resume with steps 2 and 3 listed above

**Is there anything I'm missing/wrong about before I get started with this process?**

Comment: You should resize the drive from booting to a LiveCD/DVD/USB so that you can make sure that no partitions are mounted. The key next to the partition name means that it is mounted and locked so that you can't make any changes.  Then you should be able to shrink that partition and move the swap partition next to it after you shrink it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resize partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions)

Comment: @Terrance: thanks. so no need to turnoff/remove/recreate the swap? I just boot into live CD/USD, resize `ext4` and move `swap` next to it?

Comment: Should be OK to do that.  As it stands the swap and the root `/` have UUIDs on them and as long as the UUIDs don't change, there shouldn't be any reason to modify the boot other than after the Windows install that should change the bootloader which you have planned to reinstall GRUB after.